# how to change joystick controlls in xna

Tags: xna, configure, xbox360, joystick, gamepad

exactly the title. i need it for my game.

i know how to change controlls on some games trough some programms that do exactly that, but i want to go into options screen, go change controlls, choose whether i will play on joystic or keyboard and then configure my controlls.

i googled but all i found are tutorials on how to use 360's joystick.
i would be SO grateful if anyone could enlighten me with his knowledge.
(i think that this is the first question about that on the internet)
have no code for this, and no idea of how to begin.

thatks for ANY feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean stuff like invert Y or button remapping, you have to code your own.

Comment: i mean like: i dont wanna jump on button A no more, i want to do that on button X

Comment: and yes, i want to know how to remap buttons. i could try but i don't know where to being! I wasn't even shure it was possible! can you give me the idea behind remapping?

Comment: Here is an example of using and altering gamepad button mapping. it uses an input handler class: http://pastebin.com/zU3emihB  along with the traditional game1 class: http://pastebin.com/8w7qY4Qk